# Show tickmark depending on drop down value in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dropdown

Need to tickmark this widget depending on drop down value pending
confirmed, dispatched, recieved.
if passed pending it display pending with tick and if its confirmed on
dropdown it shows confimed with two ticks and dispatched with three ticks
and so on. Tried creating drop down which selects the all four values dont understand how
to implement tickmarks based on the text value and show that widget that I made.

[image]
Please help. Thanks.

```
class OrderListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderListScreen> createState() => _OrderListScreenState();
}

class _OrderListScreenState extends State<OrderListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
                " Please select the order status from the dropdown Below:",
                style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.orange)),
            Container(
                child: Material(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                items: <String>[
                  'Pending',
                  'Confirmed',
                  'Dispatched',
                  'Recieved'
                ].map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (_) {},
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*OrderStatus Widget (that has all dropdown values):*

```
OrderStatusBar(title: widget.order.orderStatus, status: true),






class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar({Key? key, required this.title, required this.status})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;
  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          widget.status ? dottedCircleWithCheckMark() : dottedCircle(),
          const SizedBox(width: 30),
          Text(
            widget.title.tr,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: widget.status ? FontWeight.bold : null,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

const size = 25.0;
const strokeWidth = 1.0;
const checkedColor = Color.fromRGBO(232, 113, 65, 1);

Widget dottedLine() {
  return Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, size / 2, 0),
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27 / 2),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size,
            child: DottedLine(
              dashColor: Colors.black,
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              lineLength: size,
              lineThickness: strokeWidth,
              dashLength: 5,
              dashGapLength: 5,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

dottedCircle() {
  return DottedBorder(
      borderType: BorderType.Circle,
      dashPattern: const [5, 5],
      child: Container(
        height: size,
        width: size,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
      ));
}

dottedCircleWithCheckMark() {
  return Container(
    height: size + strokeWidth * 2,
    width: size + strokeWidth * 2,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: checkedColor,
    ),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: size / 4 * 3,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: where it should be shown? can you include an image

Comment: added image to show the icon based on some dropdown value and display it

Answer (score 1):

Create a callback on `OrderListScreen` to get selected item.

```dart
class OrderListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String? selectedValue) callback;
  const OrderListScreen({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderListScreen> createState() => _OrderListScreenState();
}
```

And get value from from onCHanged

```dart
onChanged: (v) {
                  widget.callback(v);
                  setState(() {
                    selectedValue = v;
                  });
                },
```

Now on parent widget.

```dart
class _AppXState extends State<AppX> {
  final items = <String>['Pending', 'Confirmed', 'Dispatched', 'Recieved'];

  int selectedItemIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          OrderListScreen(
            callback: (selectedValue) {
              if (selectedValue != null && items.contains(selectedValue)) {
                selectedItemIndex = items.indexOf(selectedValue);
                setState(() {});
              }
            },
          ),
          for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            OrderStatusBar(title: items[i], status: i <= selectedItemIndex),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Test snippet

```dart
class AppX extends StatefulWidget {
  AppX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppX> createState() => _AppXState();
}

class _AppXState extends State<AppX> {
  final items = <String>['Pending', 'Confirmed', 'Dispatched', 'Recieved'];

  int selectedItemIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          OrderListScreen(
            callback: (selectedValue) {
              if (selectedValue != null && items.contains(selectedValue)) {
                selectedItemIndex = items.indexOf(selectedValue);
                setState(() {});
              }
            },
          ),
          for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            OrderStatusBar(title: items[i], status: i <= selectedItemIndex),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OrderListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String? selectedValue) callback;
  const OrderListScreen({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderListScreen> createState() => _OrderListScreenState();
}

class _OrderListScreenState extends State<OrderListScreen> {
  String? selectedValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(" Please select the order status from the dropdown Below:",
                style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.orange)),
            Container(
                child: Material(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: selectedValue,
                items: <String>[
                  'Pending',
                  'Confirmed',
                  'Dispatched',
                  'Recieved'
                ].map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(value),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (v) {
                  widget.callback(v);
                  setState(() {
                    selectedValue = v;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```